# Does the Goblin Hexer's Vexing Cloud grant concealment and an additional -2 to hit?

Tags: dnd-4e, zone, concealment

The **Goblin Hexer's Vexing Cloud** is a standard action with a zone:

> Area burst 3 within 10; automatic hit;
>   all enemies within the zone take a -2
>   penalty to attack rolls.  The zone
>   grants concealment to the goblin hexer
>   and its allies.  The goblin hexer can
>   sustain the zone as a minor action,
>   moving it up to 5 squares.

If the **Hexer** centers the blast on himself and it grants him concealment, do melee attackers then take an additional -2 to hit because of the effects of the cloud.

To break this down, assuming that concealment grants the Hexer +2 bonus to defense, and the cloud make its attacker take a -2 to attack.

Does that mean that the attack modifier from the cloud is -4?
(-2 concealment + -2 cloud effect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**

Any enemies within the zone will have an effective -4 to attack rolls.  Enemies outside the zone only take a -2 from the concealment.